# Google Cloud Functions - How to correctly setup the default credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm using Google Cloud Functions to listen to a topic in Pub/Sub and send data to a collection in Firestore. The problem is: whenever I test the function (using the test tab that is provided in GCP) and check the logs from that function, it *always* throws this error:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials.
Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
```

That link didn't help, by the way, as they say the Application Default Credentials are found automatically, but it's not the case here.

This is how I'm using Firestore, in `index.js`:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
var db = admin.firestore()
// ...
db.collection('...').add(doc)
```

In my `package.json`, these are the dependencies (I'm using BigQuery too, which raises the same error):

```
{
  "name": "[function name]",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.18.0",
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^4.3.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.1"
  }
}
```

I've already tried:

- Creating a new service account and using it in the function setting;
- Using the command `gcloud auth application-default login` in Cloud Shell;
- Setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` via Cloud Shell to a json file (I don't even know if that makes sense);

But nothing seems to work :( How can I configure this default credential so that I don't have to ever configure it again? Like, a permanent setting for the entire project so all my functions can have access to Firestore, BigQuery, IoT Core, etc. with no problems.

Comment: Which node runtime are you targeting?  BTW setting env vars in Cloud Shell will not affect how Cloud Functions behaves.

Comment: Node.js 8. Yeah, that's what I noticed after some time... I was wondering, if that variable should be a path to a json file, then where should that file be located? In my GCP VM? I have no idea, and there's no info about that on pages I've found.

Comment: One thing that made it work, though, (I just found this right now) was activating the function multiple times in a short time period, but I don't know if it's always gonna work like that. In other words, I'm not sure if it's working because of some temporary setting I made before, like `gcloud auth application-default login`, or if it's really gonna be like that all the time.

Comment: When testing locally you should set the environment variable on your local test environment (i.e. the shell/terminal where you run your code). No additional set up is necessary when running in the cloud, as GCP runtimes will automatically provision default credentials for your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I am using:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("./key.json");



const config = {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project",
    storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
 };

 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 const db = admin.firestore();
```